# I am to go / I have to go

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

There is a sentence from GoT: `I'm to go north to the Wall.` Are there any differences between the sentences:

> I am to go north
>
> I have to go north

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to go North

This is a common way of expressing obligation in modern English.

> I am to go North.

This is a rare, possibly old-fashioned, or extra formal way to express future events that can't be avoided. Not so much obligation, but a certain future.

> You are to be executed at dawn.
>   You have to be executed at dawn.

Comparing these.  The second suggests that the speaker would try to stop the execution. The first doesn't carry that implication.  A judge passing sentence would use the first expression.

People rarely talk like this, except when acting in films with an "old-world" theme.